# Why doesn't this FM receiver work in LTspice?

Tags: rf, ltspice, simulation, radio, frequency-modulation

After years, I'm back again to the electronic world. To start off, I just tried to simulate this circuit in LTspice:

[image]
[Source](https://www.eleccircuit.com/small-fm-radio-receiver/)

Here is what I've done in LTspice:

[image]

But it doesn't work. Here is a screenshot for the signal of the ANT:

[image]

And the output of the speaker:

[image]

[image]

Why doesn't it work? Any idea?

**Edit1:** Here is the screenshot for 100 MHz frequency:

[image]

**Edit2:** Here is the screenshot for 100 MHz frequency (corrected):

[image]

Comment: What carrier frequency? What modulation frequency? What depth of modulation? Or, put more simply, what did you expect to see?

Comment: (100kHz carrier, no modulation? What do you expect, what makes you state `It doesn't work`?)

Comment: @Andyaka Hey Andy, How you doing man? I think 100MHz should be Ok. FM!

Comment: @greybeard 100kHz is just to test the circuit.

Comment: You need a circa 100 MHz carrier; your screen shot shows 100 kHz on the antenna. That is miles off.

Comment: @greybeard I expect to get amplified signal on speaker lable.

Comment: @Andyaka You're right but it doesn't matter to use 100kHz or 100MHz. The result isn't desirable.

Comment: @Andyaka I can send you the file of simulation. Would you like to take a look at it?

Comment: No not really. What modulation frequency and what modulation depth (as per my first comment)? And, what did you expect to see?

Comment: @Roh First, the values for the components depend critically on frequency, so 100MHz vs 100kHz is a big deal.

Second, look how radio works eg ("frequency-modulation" on wiki). The signal is a carrier (so it can go through the air) which changes is some way (frequency or amplitude, say) to carry the signal. A radio takes this change off the carrier and creates the signal. You have a pure, unchanging carrier and so the radio is doing the right thing: nothing. You are inputting a radio station broadcasting silence!

SPICE is doing fine; your model is (probably) fine. Feed in a good signal.

Comment: 100M in spice-talk is 100 milli hertz. 100Meg in spice-talk is 100 MHz

Comment: @Andyaka Aha! What a mistake! Another edit added to the question.

Comment: @DanSheppard How much voltage is sufficient as input?

Comment: @Roh --> the answers to the three other questions that I've now asked twice are? I suspect that if you don't know what modulation frequency and depth are then, what you see is exactly right.

Comment: @Roh if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering this question because it's easier than leaving any more comments: -

> *Why doesn't this FM receiver work in LTSpice?*

You haven't done anything that suggests you can make that statement because, it looks to me like it should work on paper. For instance, you originally used a carrier frequency of 10 kHz when, clearly stated in the linked article in your question; the carrier frequency is circa 100 MHz.

But, you can't just feed a pure carrier into the receiver antenna input and expect to see some audio signal on the demodulated output. Your carrier needs to be modulated like this: -

[image]

- trace_A should be the unmodulated carrier at 100 MHz
- trace_B is the modulating signal (typically 1 kHz)
- trace_D is the modulated carrier

<sub>Trace_C is irrelevant to frequency modulation so ignore it.</sub>

A signal like trace_D is what needs feeding into your receiver. If the carrier is 100 MHz then maybe the modulation signal moves this up to 100.1 MHz and down to 99.9 MHz by the act of modulation.

You don't appear to have a signal that modulates the carrier. You need one or, the output will flat-line as you are currently seeing.